# Why does Blender suddenly not select vertices directly undernearth the one I am selecting in wireframe mode?

Tags: interface, vertices, selection-tools

I'm working in Blender, and I'm in wireframe mode in ortho view, and when I select a vertex it will also select the vertex that is directly underneath it. Suddenly this behaviour no longer happens. What's the deal and how do I get Blender to go back to its original behaviour?

Comment: Has this ever been a feature, I always thought that it just ambiguously chose one to select. You can use box select though to help though, just hit `B`

Comment: Blender always selects 1 vertice on click if you aren't using a modifier key. Use circle select C or box select B in wireframe mode if you need to select multiple overlapping vertices.